# Multi conditional with double conditional in R

Tags: r

I have a with a statement with multiple conditionals like below

```
with(x_in
  [
    x_in$Power_KW < 1700 
    & x_in$Power_KW  > 0 
    & x_in$Power_KW  < x_in$Expected_Power_KW*1.1 
    & x_in$Power_KW  > x_in$Expected_Power_KW*.9
  ,], 

    plot(x_in$Wind_Speed_, x_in$Power_KW ,col="gray48"
      ,main= titlename, col.main = "black", cex=.5,pch=16
      ,col.lab="black",col.axis = 'black',cex.lab=1.25
      ,xlim=c(0, 25), ylim=c(0, 1800))
    )
```

This works perfectly fine, but I need to add an additional condition where I filter additional data where both "Wind_Speed_" is greater than 12 and the "Power_KW" is greater than 1550. Both of these must be true for additional filtering.

I  know there needs to be an additional AND statement but I don't know how to do it with multiple true conditions. I tried looking into using `exists`, but I don't think I know the syntax, or how it exactly works. This might also not be the best way to handle the problem.

Thanks!

EDIT: To addtional clarity - I only want to filter out data for "Power_KW" that is less than 1550 ONLY IF the "Wind_Speed_" is greater than 12. If "Wind_Speed_" is less than 12 I don't want anything done to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with(x_in
  [
    (x_in$Power_KW < 1700 & x_in$Power_KW > 1550)
    # & x_in$Power_KW  > 0                        This is redundant
    & x_in$Power_KW  < x_in$Expected_Power_KW*1.1 
    & x_in$Power_KW  > x_in$Expected_Power_KW*.9
    & x_in$Wind_Speed_ > 12
  ,], 

    plot(x_in$Wind_Speed_, x_in$Power_KW ,col="gray48"
      ,main= titlename, col.main = "black", cex=.5,pch=16
      ,col.lab="black",col.axis = 'black',cex.lab=1.25
      ,xlim=c(0, 25), ylim=c(0, 1800))
    )
```

Since you said the conditions need to apply together, we can just add all of them together as & conditions.

EDIT:

I am assuming your first set of filters are correct, and you need to further filter out some rows based on the new conditions you mentioned.

```
x_filtered <- x_in
  [
    x_in$Power_KW < 1700 
    & x_in$Power_KW  > 0 
    & x_in$Power_KW  < x_in$Expected_Power_KW*1.1 
    & x_in$Power_KW  > x_in$Expected_Power_KW*.9
  ,]
```

On this intermediate data.frame, we can apply the additional filter:

```
x_final <- x_filtered[(x_filtered$Wind_Speed_ < 12) | 
                      (x_filtered$Wind_Speed_ > 12 & x_filtered$Power_KW > 1550), ]
```

You can do this at one go like so:

```
x_final <- x_in
      [
        x_in$Power_KW < 1700 
        & x_in$Power_KW  > 0 
        & x_in$Power_KW  < x_in$Expected_Power_KW*1.1 
        & x_in$Power_KW  > x_in$Expected_Power_KW*.9
      ,][(x_filtered$Wind_Speed_ < 12) | 
         (x_filtered$Wind_Speed_ > 12 & x_filtered$Power_KW > 1550), ]
```

Comment: No, sorry, maybe I wasn't clear. This doesn't work because I still need the data that could be less than a "Wind_Speed_" of 12 regardless of what the "Power_KW" is.

Comment: So... (wind_speed > 12 & power_kw > 1550) | (wind_speed < 12) ?

Comment: no, it's more like if wind_speed >12 and Power_kw > 1550, I want to keep it.

Comment: Yes, that is what the code does. The condition evaluates to true when (1) wind_speed < 12. And (2) when wind_speed > 12 and power_kw > 1550

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood properly but you just need for a condition that combines two statements that need to be true. The use of parenthesis is what you need.

```
 with(x_in
      [
        x_in$Power_KW < 1700 
        & x_in$Power_KW  > 0 
        & x_in$Power_KW  < x_in$Expected_Power_KW*1.1 
        & x_in$Power_KW  > x_in$Expected_Power_KW*.9
        &(x_in$Wind_Speed_ > 12 & x_in$Power_KW > 1550)
      ,], 

        plot(x_in$Wind_Speed_, x_in$Power_KW ,col="gray48"
          ,main= titlename, col.main = "black", cex=.5,pch=16
          ,col.lab="black",col.axis = 'black',cex.lab=1.25
          ,xlim=c(0, 25), ylim=c(0, 1800))
        )
```

Comment: This was my initial attempt as well, but this eliminates all data that where wind_speed is less than 12. I need that still. I just want to get rid of the data where wind speed is over 12 but is under 1550.